# How add some css in stored values with django autocomplete-light?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I overrided get_results method of autocomplete-light as follow to have single tag in bold:

**views.py**

```
class TagAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = Tag.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs


    def get_results(self, context):
        results_list = []
        for result in context["object_list"]:
            text2show = "{}"
            tag_occurrences = result.org_set.count()

            if tag_occurrences == 1:
                text2show = '<b>{}</b>';

            results_list.append({
                "id": self.get_result_value(result),
                "text": format_html(text2show, self.get_result_label(result)),
                "selected_text": format_html(text2show, self.get_selected_result_label(result)),
            })

        return results_list
```

Everything works perfectly if I search a tag, but if I try to view a stored event, all its tags are represented without any style.

**forms.py**

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = "__all__" 

        widgets = {
            'tags': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='myapp:tag-autocomplete', attrs={'data-html': True})
        }


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # if I try to edit an event
        if self.instance:

            # self.fields['tag'].queryset = ???
```

And this is a piece of my template:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in myform %}
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{field.label}}</label><div class="col-sm-4">
        {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ myform.media }}
</form>
```

Is there a way to manipulate *self.fields['tag'].queryset* queryset to show field names in bold or another elegant solution?

Thanks.

**update**
**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Tag name', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        return mark_safe("<b>%s</b>" % self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: try this => `attrs={'data-html': True, 'style': "font-size: 10;"}`

Comment: It does not work, but even if it worked I would like only the chosen tags to be in bold

Comment: in forms.py or in model.py? I didn't understand

Comment: change it in models.py

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion but I have this error: _'Tag' object has no attribute '_state'_

Comment: sorry my bad, change the `Tag.__str__` in models.py, remove `__init__`

Comment: in Tag.__str__ bold works if I return `return "<b>{}</b>".format(self.name)`. With `return mark_safe("<b>%s</b>" % self.name)` it does not works. Very strange!